# asp.net mvc - how to update dropdown list in tinyMCE

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Scenario: I have a standard dropdown list and when the value in that dropdownlist changes I want to update another dropdownlist that exists in a tinyMCE control.

Currently it does what I want when I open the page (i.e. the first time)...

```
function changeParent() {

    }

tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.MoePlugin', {
            createControl: function(n, cm) {
                switch (n) {
                    case 'mylistbox':
                        var mlb = cm.createListBox('mylistbox', {
                            title: 'Inserts',
                            onselect: function(v) {
                                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceInsertContent",false,v);                                                                
                            }
                        });

                        <% foreach (var insert in (ViewData["Inserts"] as List<String>)) { %> // This is .NET 
                            yourobject = '<%= insert %>'; // This is JS AND .NET
                            mlb.add(yourobject, yourobject); // This is JavaScript
                        <% } %>                       

                        // Return the new listbox instance
                        return mlb;
                }
                return null;
            }
        });             


<%= Html.DropDownList(Model.Record[184].ModelEntity.ModelEntityId.ToString(), ViewData["Containers"] as SelectList, new { onchange = "changeParent(); return false;" })%>
```

I am thinking the way to accomplish this (in the ChangeParentFunction) is to call a controller action to get a new list, then grab the 'mylistbox' object and reassign it, but am unsure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 - Provide a JsonResult in your controller**

```
    public JsonResult GetInserts(int containerId)
    {
        //some code to get list of inserts here 
        List<string> somedata = doSomeStuff();

        return Json(somedata);
    }
```

**Step 2 - Create javascript function to get Json results**

```
function getInserts() {
    var params = {};
    params.containerId = $("#184").val();
    $.getJSON("GetInserts", params, updateInserts);
};

updateInserts = function(data) {
    var insertsElem = document.getElementById("183_mylistbox");

    insertsElem.options.length = 1;  // Remove all but the first option.

    var optElem = document.createElement("option");
    for (var item in data) {
        optElem = document.createElement("option");
        optElem.value = item;
        optElem.text = data[item];

        try {  
            insertsElem.add(optElem, null); // standards compliant browsers  
        }  
        catch(ex) {  
            insertsElem.add(optElem, item+1); // IE only (second paramater is the items position in the list) 
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 3 - Create NativeListBox (code above provided by ZoogieZork above)**

```
var mlb = cm.createListBox('mylistbox', {
    title: 'Inserts'
}, tinymce.ui.NativeListBox);

// Set our own change handler.
mlb.onPostRender.add(function(t) {
    tinymce.dom.Event.add(t.id, 'change', function(e) {
        var v = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, v);
        e.target.selectedIndex = 0;
    });
});

//populate inserts on listbox create
getInserts();
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as updating the TinyMCE listbox goes, you can try using a `tinymce.ui.NativeListBox` instead of the standard `tinymce.ui.ListBox`.  You can do this by setting the last argument to `cm.createListBox` to `tinymce.ui.NativeListBox`.  This way, you'll have a regular old `<select>` that you can update as you normally would.

The downside is that it looks like you'll need to manually hook up your own onchange listener since `NativeListBox` maintains its own list of items internally.

**EDIT:**

I played around a bit with this last night and here's what I've come up with.

First, here's how to use a native list box and wire up our own onChange handler, the TinyMCE way:

```
// Create a NativeListBox so we can easily modify the contents of the list.
var mlb = cm.createListBox('mylistbox', {
    title: 'Inserts'
}, tinymce.ui.NativeListBox);

// Set our own change handler.
mlb.onPostRender.add(function(t) {
    tinymce.dom.Event.add(t.id, 'change', function(e) {
        var v = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, v);
        e.target.selectedIndex = 0;
    });
});
```

As far as updating the list box at runtime, your idea of calling a controller action to get the new items is sound; I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, so I can't really help you there.

The ID of the `<select>` that TinyMCE creates takes the form *editorId*_*controlId*, where in your case *controlId* is "mylistbox".  Firebug in Firefox is the easiest way to find the ID of the `<select>` :)

Here's the test button I added to my page to check if the above code was working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doFoo() {
    // Change "myEditor" below to the ID of your TinyMCE instance.
    var insertsElem = document.getElementById("myEditor_mylistbox");

    insertsElem.options.length = 1;  // Remove all but the first option.

    var optElem = document.createElement("option");
    optElem.value = "1";
    optElem.text = "Foo";
    insertsElem.add(optElem, null);

    optElem = document.createElement("option");
    optElem.value = "2";
    optElem.text = "Bar";
    insertsElem.add(optElem, null);
}
</script>
<button onclick="doFoo();">FOO</button>
```

Hope this helps, or at least gets you started.

Comment: Sounds intreging, I a a bit of a javascript noob, however.  Can you give me an example please.

Comment: Thanks ZoogieZork, I will have another coffee and give it a go!

Comment: I get an error: htmlfile: Type mismatch. on the "insertsElem.add(optElem, null);" statement

Comment: Stepping through to that point I can see all of the original list items, then see all but the first one being deleted (length = 1), so its good up until that point.

Comment: Ah, looks like IE handles `add()` on a select element slightly differently than other browser.  http://www.coderanch.com/t/119339/HTML-JavaScript/What-s-Wrong-With-My